# Cordova/Ionic on Android, JS plugin files not arriving on device (seen via inspect device)

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

For android, some .js plugin files (eg for phonegap-facebook-plugin) are not arriving on device when I inspect device.

On iOS, I need to do “Target Membership” for that plugin, but on Android, there’s no such option.

I even try to include the file in my index.html, but it doesn't seem to get included.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because of 2 reasons:

1) not doing exactly this: prepare -> refresh -> build

2) js error, as seen in inspect, causing old code to run